# How can I select a column from my table, and get very nth row based on the value in that column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table called DIVISION filled with numeric values. They are not unique. There is a person as reach record and they have a DIVISION assigned to them. I want to be able to select every nth row in my table based on the DIVISION.

So say if DIVISION 211 has 60k records and we select every nth row and get 13k records. Then we move on to say 222 which has 100k records and we select 23k.

Also, I need to be able to start counting each nth row after the first 13. So basically, go to 13 and use that as the starting point. After 13 select every nth row.

I honestly have no idea where to even begin with this, I tried a bunch of examples from Google and most of the time I couldn't even get the syntax correct enough to run.

I found something for MySQL that seems like it could somewhat do what I want, but I couldn't figure out the SQL Server equivalent of this.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, noun
     FROM 
         (SELECT @row :=0) r, nouns) ranked
WHERE rownum %4 =1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes you have a late enough version of SQL Server to use `row_number()`. It's very likely you do:

```
with data as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by DIVISION order by <sort by column>) as rn
    from WORK
)
select *
from data
where rn <= 13 or (rn - 13) % 18 = 1;
```

Comment: Hm, it actually gives me a syntax error for this. It says I need to set my compatibility mode to 90.

Comment: @rohanharrison You didn't supply your query so I have no way of incorporating it into that logic. Did you insert your original query correctly?

Comment: @rohanharrison . . . Set your compatibility to a modern version of SQL Server.  `row_number()` has been supported since 2005; there is no reason to use an older, unsupported version.

Comment: @rohanharrison You also need to put the appropriate columns in the `order by`.

Comment: @shawnt00 I figured it out I just forgot to put in the order by. I'm playing with it right now because it does not do exactly what it needs to do but i'm not sure what the problem is. I should be getting roughly 70k records and i'm getting 98k.

Comment: @shawnt00 Say I need to start at 13 and get every 18th record, what would I need to change about it exactly?

Comment: @rohanharrison Sounds like you just change the 4 to 18.

Comment: @shawnt00 That's what I thought. Okay actually this works exactly how I need to I just needed to change the numbers around. Thank you!

Comment: @rohanharrison Actually I approved your edit but partitioning and ordering by the same column doesn't make sense. You really need to sort on a different column.